# Using Event::Lib to make a perl chat client

Tags: perl, sockets, event-handling, client

I am trying to learn perl and also event driven programming. I have made a client, which attached to a specific IP and port number and listens for messages over the socket.

```
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerHost => $server,
PeerPort => '5000',
Proto => 'tcp',
);
```

Then I listen for the server messages and also I want to read from the STDIN. For that I tried implementing event programming using the library `Event::Lib` from CPAN

```
sub do_client{
my ($ev,$type) = @_;
my $event = shift;
my $fh = $event->fh;
$cl_data = <$fh>;
chomp $cl_data;
print $socket "$cl_data\r\n";
$event->add; 
}

sub do_server{
my ($ev,$type) = @_;
my $event = shift;
my $fh = $event->fh;
$sv_data = <$fh>;
chomp $sv_data;
print "$sv_data\n";
$event->add;
}


event_new($socket, EV_WRITE, \&do_server)->add;
event_new(STDIN, EV_WRITE, \&do_client)->add;
event_mainloop;
```

Now the problem is. After every line read from the socket the handler I think goes to the STDIN event and waits for a return from me. If I dont press return from my keyboard the handler never goes and reads from the socket and prints it. ( its not getting sync the client and server communications )

This is the way I get the output.

```
Connection established
[Server]
    **** waits here for me to enter return *** 
Whats your name?
```

I am trying to make a chat client. So it should go to STDIN event whenever I write to the terminal and print out the message whenever there is one in the socket.
Please tell what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Looking at the Event::Lib page the STDIN call should be       event_new(\*STDIN, EV_READ, \&handler)->add(1.5);   I would still go with AnyEvent as per my answer

Comment: I would recommend not using Event::Lib at all - the underlying C library is fine, but the module is very broken and not maintained anymore (inevitably causing random memory corruption). Some better alternatives are Event, Glib, EV and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a higher level module with your code. When you do a `<STDIN>` then it will block

[AnyEvent](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/AnyEvent-7.05/lib/AnyEvent.pm) provides non blocking IO with event driven programming

```
   my $w; $w = AnyEvent->io (fh => \*STDIN, poll => 'r', cb => sub {
      chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);
      warn "read: $input\n";
      undef $w;
   });
```

which will non block on STDIN and then clear the watcher with

```
undef $w;
```

Comment: hum, you made it blocking by using `<>`, which reads until a newline is encountered. You shouldn't be using `<>` in there. You should only read what's available, add it to a buffer, and check if there's a newline in the buffer.

Comment: AnyEvent::IO takes care of that by only firing the event when its safe to read a line. If the OP is after something to wait on a keypress http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/AnyEvent-TermKey-0.02/lib/AnyEvent/TermKey.pm but I haven't used this one

Comment: No, it fires the event when there is *data* to read. ("`cb` is the callback to invoke each time the file handle becomes ready.") There might not be a *line*